# Date based get that monthly report in php

Tags: php, mysql, date, group-by, between

Given Date is **2015-08-10** but i need to get the August month report.Do not use(BETWEEN **2015-08-01** and **2015-08-31**).Please advise me.

date                qty

2015-08-10         10

2015-08-20          2
2015-08-21         12

2015-09-01         5

Comment: Your question is unclear - are you asking 'how can I select everything for the current month?'

Comment: Could you please show some code ? Example datas ? Have you tried anything ? It's hard to understand what you exactly want here.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow, please visit the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

```
     Now we are use BETWEEN for getting august month report 1 to 31. 

       $var2=' 2015-08-10';
      $date2 = str_replace('/', '-', $var2);

       // First day of the month.
      $From=date('Y-m-01', strtotime($date2));

      // Last day of the month.
      $To=date('Y-m-t', strtotime($date2));
```